# Generalize recognized amounts across month long columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'payment_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'amount': [99.99, 19.99, 149.99, 9.99, 9.99, 179.99],
    'period': ['annual', 'annual', 'annual', 'monthly', 'monthly', 'biannual'],
    'starts_at': ['2021-02-01', '2021-02-14', '2021-02-28', '2021-02-14', '2021-02-01', '2021-02-14'],
    'ends_at': ['2022-02-01', '2022-02-14', '2022-02-28', '2021-03-14', '2021-03-01', '2021-8-14']
})

df['starts_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['starts_at'])
df['ends_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ends_at'])
df['amount_per_day'] = df['amount'] / (df['ends_at'] - df['starts_at']).dt.days
```

Multiple periods exist, I have come up with the following solution for annual payments in order to break out the amount over each day of the payment.

```
df['month_start'] = (((df['starts_at'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)) 
                  - df['starts_at']).dt.days + 1) * df['amount_per_day']

for i in range(1, 12):
    df[f'month_{i}'] = ((df['starts_at'] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(i)
                        ).dt.days_in_month * df['amount_per_day'])

df['month_end'] = (df['ends_at'] - (df['ends_at'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) 
                  - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(normalize=True))).dt.days * df['amount_per_day']
```

Example, we can confirm for the annual periods, the sum of the broken out month's amounts are indeed equal to the amount

```
df[df['period'] == 'annual'].filter(regex='month_').sum(axis=1)

0     99.99
1     19.99
2    149.99
dtype: float64
```

However, I obtain erroneous values for monthly and biannual. My goal is to **generalize** to where one need not even know the period. Is there a more pandas-esque way to split out numerics across columns?

Edit:

If I remove the erroneous values as follows, the expected output is then

```
df.loc[(df['period'] == 'monthly', 'month_1')] = np.nan
df.loc[(df['period'] == 'monthly', 'month_2')] = np.nan
df.loc[(df['period'] == 'monthly', 'month_3')] = np.nan
df.loc[(df['period'] == 'monthly', 'month_4')] = np.nan
df.loc[(df['period'] == 'monthly', 'month_5')] = np.nan
df.loc[(df['period'] == 'monthly', 'month_6')] = np.nan
df.loc[(df['period'] == 'monthly', 'month_7')] = np.nan
df.loc[(df['period'] == 'monthly', 'month_8')] = np.nan
df.loc[(df['period'] == 'monthly', 'month_9')] = np.nan
df.loc[(df['period'] == 'monthly', 'month_10')] = np.nan
df.loc[(df['period'] == 'monthly', 'month_11')] = np.nan

df.loc[(df['period'] == 'biannual', 'month_6')] = np.nan
df.loc[(df['period'] == 'biannual', 'month_7')] = np.nan
df.loc[(df['period'] == 'biannual', 'month_8')] = np.nan
df.loc[(df['period'] == 'biannual', 'month_9')] = np.nan
df.loc[(df['period'] == 'biannual', 'month_10')] = np.nan
df.loc[(df['period'] == 'biannual', 'month_11')] = np.nan 

df.filter(regex='month_').sum(axis=1) 
0     99.99
1     19.99
2    149.99
3      9.99
4      9.99
5    179.99
dtype: float64
```

But doing this requires knowing the period in the first place, which I don't really want to do

Comment: how many different periods do you have in your data? the way you are currently doing can be done a bit better but is the most simple solution if you don`t have many periods and new one can't be added

Comment: right now just 1 month and 1 year periods, but n-month periods will be added in the future (up to 12)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following, although it requires a way too large memory space. Any other solutions appreciated!

```
sdf = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(df['starts_at'].min(), df['ends_at'].max()), 
                      columns=['day']).assign(k=1)
sdf['month'] = sdf['day'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(normalize=True)

m = pd.merge(df, sdf, on='k')

m[(m['day'] >= m['starts_at']) & (m['day'] < m['ends_at'])].groupby(['month'])['amount_per_day'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an idea creating first a column with the number of month from the difference of start and end date. Then in the loop for, use this value to compare with the loop number to fill only the wanted rows:

```
# here column with number of month
df['nb_month'] = (df['ends_at'] - df['starts_at']) // np.timedelta64(1, 'M')

df['month_start'] = (((df['starts_at'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)) 
                  - df['starts_at']).dt.days + 1) * df['amount_per_day']

for i in range(1, 12):
    df[f'month_{i}'] = (
        np.where(df['nb_month'].ge(i), # check where month is supposed to be calculated
                 ((df['starts_at'] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(i)
                        ).dt.days_in_month * df['amount_per_day']),
                 0) # else fill with 0
    )

df['month_end'] = (df['ends_at'] - (df['ends_at'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) 
                  - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(normalize=True))).dt.days*df['amount_per_day']

print(df.filter(regex='month_').sum(1).to_frame(name='sum_months')
        .join(df.filter(regex='amount')))
   sum_months  amount  amount_per_day
0       99.99   99.99        0.273945
1       19.99   19.99        0.054767
2      149.99  149.99        0.410932
3        9.99    9.99        0.356786
4        9.99    9.99        0.356786
5      179.99  179.99        0.994420
```